# Apply Conditional Formatting based on proximity to a list of multiple different values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I have two columns of numbers that are calculated values for two different capacitors that I will be using in a circuit. I would like to highlight entries that are close to a list of standard capacitor values.

Is there a good way to do this?

Here is a screenshot of a small portion of data that I have to go off of:

[image: Here is a screenshot of a small portion of data that I have to go off of.]

Comment: Would you say the question is the same if you had only one column (C1) and not two?  (I'm asking this to make sure C1 and C2 don't work together somehow in getting your result.)

Comment: @Smandoli C1 and C2 work together (I have a total of 4 capacitors, C1-C4). I need to find a single row where all 4 capacitors are close to a standard value. For the sake of this question, I'm assuming that I'll be able to look through the data and find a row where all 4 are highlighted based off of a tolerance that I set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try CF with following formula:

```
=OR(ABS(A1/TRANSPOSE($F$2:$F$12)-1)<=$G$2)
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Can you explain the first `A1` before the `/TRANSPOSE` ?

Comment: @JakeNixon Any formula for CF must be written taking into account the AppliesTo range. In this case, formatting is applied to the ```A1:D20``` range and the formula is written for the upper left cell, despite the fact that in the first row it will return an error (which CF will translate as ```FALSE```).

Answer (score 1):

I’m assuming you’re asking “are any of the C1 or C2 close to any of the standard values listed”

With that assumption, I would do it this way:

Create some “calculation rows” away from the raw data. For each C1(or C2) value, make a column of =(C1-standard value)/C1 then apply the conditional formatting on that. If any of them get close enough, say 5%, then make it green.

You’ll have a big 2D grid (every C1 or C2) vs (every standard value). It should be easy to see if any pop out green!

Comment: I'll have a 2D grid where each column is something like "C1 proximity to standard value x", and another 2D grid for C2? I have a total of 4 capacitors, so four grids of comparison data? Each row is a different calculated value for the capacitor that I already have?

Comment: Yes. If organizationally you want to keep as separate grids, I would suggest putting each on its own sheet. Or you could have it as one long 2D grid with another column on the left specifying whether the row is C1, C2 or C3,... this will give you C values going down and proximity to each standard value going across. Then you can easily make it a filter table so that you can switch between whether you want to display C1, or C2 or all of them at once.

Comment: Well, the point of this is to be able to look down the list and easily see a row of 4 columns, and find one that has the narrowest tolerances. The large arrays of data makes this a bit more tricky. Do you have any recommendations to get this easier for review?

Comment: Yeah definitely. Just stack the 2x2 into one long table. To tell the difference between C1, C2, C3 or C4 data, add another column on the left